# XML XPath check if node exist... then

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have a complex XML exported from a dB. Thanks to [Hakre's answer to my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31402767/php-xpath-convert-complex-xml-to-array) I can now convert the XML - with PHP - into an array as wished.

The conversion of the XML into an array is almost perfect, but there's still an issue that I would like to fix.

The part of the XML I'm working on is the following:

```
<comma>
    <num><num>
    <alinea>Lorem ipsum...</alinea>
</comma>
<comma>
    <num></num>
    <corpo>dolor sit amet...</corpo>
</comma>
```

Don't ask me why, but as you may see from this excerpt sometimes the child of `comma` is `alinea` and sometimes the child is `corpo`.

Now I can convert the above excerpt of the XML into an array using [Hakre's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31402767/php-xpath-convert-complex-xml-to-array):

```
<commi expr="a:comma">
    <num_alinea expr="concat(a:num, a:alinea)"/>
</commi>
```

But this will get only the `alinea` tag so I had to change it into:

```
<commi expr="a:comma">  
    <num_alinea expr="string(a:alinea)"/>
    <num_corpo expr="string(a:corpo)"/>
</commi>
```

The above code will work but the array generated will output like this:

```
Array
    (
        [num_alinea] => Lorem ipsum...
        [num_corpo] =>
    )
```

or

```
Array
    (
        [num_alinea] =>
        [num_corpo] => dolor sit amet...
    )
```

Where `num_alinea` or `num_corpo` are empty or not depending on the existence of the tags `alinea` or `corpo` in the XML.

**Can I add a conditional statement to the XML `expr`** above? I suppose I have to use something like this:

```
<text expr="boolean(a:alinea)"/>
```

but I don't know how to instruct XPath to say:

```
"if exists node [alinea] then get its content, if exist node [corpo] then get its content".
```

I'm not sure **about the origin of the expressions in the `expr` tag**. Are these XPath expressions? Where I can find more about them? Is there a manual/tutorial or simply a list of statements to learn on?