# Iterating through XML with SimpleXML and XPath, Result is in wrong order

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

my variables.php

```
$xmlFile = 'xml.xml';
$xmlFileLoad = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile);
$xmlFileLoad->registerXPathNamespace("oi", "http://www.openimmo.de");
$immobilie = $xmlFileLoad->xpath('//oi:immobilie');

$zustand_angaben_letztemodernisierung = $xmlFileLoad->xpath('/oi:openimmo/oi:immobilie/oi:zustand_angaben/oi:letztemodernisierung');
$zustand_angaben_zustand = $xmlFileLoad->xpath('/oi:openimmo/oi:immobilie/oi:zustand_angaben/oi:zustand/@zustand_art');
$zustand_angaben_alter = $xmlFileLoad->xpath('/oi:openimmo/oi:immobilie/oi:zustand_angaben/oi:alter/@alter_attr');
$zustand_angaben_erschliessung = $xmlFileLoad->xpath('/oi:openimmo/oi:immobilie/oi:zustand_angaben/oi:erschliessung/@erschl_attr');
$zustand_angaben_altlasten = $xmlFileLoad->xpath('/oi:openimmo/oi:immobilie/oi:zustand_angaben/oi:altlasten');
$zustand_angaben_baujahr = $xmlFileLoad->xpath('/oi:openimmo/oi:immobilie/oi:zustand_angaben/oi:baujahr');
```

the xml file (shorted version)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openimmo xmlns="http://www.openimmo.de"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openimmo.de openimmo.xsd">
    <immobilie>
        <zustand_angaben>
            <altlasten>keine</altlasten>
        </zustand_angaben>
    </immobilie>
    <immobilie>
        <zustand_angaben>
            <altlasten>keine</altlasten>
        </zustand_angaben>
    </immobilie>
    <immobilie>
        <zustand_angaben>
            <altlasten>keine</altlasten>
        </zustand_angaben>
    </immobilie>
    <immobilie>
        <zustand_angaben>
            <baujahr>ca. 1900</baujahr>
            <altlasten>nein</altlasten>
        </zustand_angaben>
    </immobilie>
    <immobilie>
        <zustand_angaben>
            <baujahr>ca. 1989</baujahr>
            <zustand zustand_art="ERSTBEZUG" />
            <alter alter_attr="ALTBAU" />
            <altlasten>keine</altlasten>
        </zustand_angaben>
    </immobilie>
</openimmo>
```

my show.php

```
<?php
    include("variables.php");

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($immobilie as $immo) {

        echo "Immobilie $i<br />";
        if(isset($zustand_angaben_zustand[$i])) {
            echo $zustand_angaben_zustand[$i] . "</br>";
        }

        if(isset($zustand_angaben_alter[$i])) {
            echo $zustand_angaben_alter[$i] . "</br>";
        }

        if(isset($zustand_angaben_erschliessung[$i])) {
            echo $zustand_angaben_erschliessung[$i] . "</br>";
        }

        if(isset($zustand_angaben_altlasten[$i])) {
            echo $zustand_angaben_altlasten[$i] . "</br>";
        }

        if(isset($zustand_angaben_baujahr[$i])) {
            echo $zustand_angaben_baujahr[$i] . "</br>";
        }   
        echo "<br /><br />";
        $i++;
    }
?>
```

when i'm executing the code, the result will be the following

```
Immobilie 0
ERSTBEZUG
ALTBAU
keine
5
A
5
A++
ca. 1900

Immobilie 1
keine

ca. 1989

Immobilie 2
keine

Immobilie 3
nein

Immobilie 4
keine
```

but i want it in the order like in the xml, so Immobilie 0 has only keine, Immobilie 1 and 2 too, the third 1900 and nein and last but not least Immobilie 4 with all the properties in the xml...

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use XPath expressions that relative to current `immobilie` element instead :

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($immobilie as $immo) {
    $immo->registerXPathNamespace("oi", "http://www.openimmo.de");
    $zustand_angaben_letztemodernisierung = $immo->xpath('./oi:zustand_angaben/oi:letztemodernisierung');
    $zustand_angaben_zustand = $immo->xpath('./oi:zustand_angaben/oi:zustand/@zustand_art');
    $zustand_angaben_alter = $immo->xpath('./oi:zustand_angaben/oi:alter/@alter_attr');
    $zustand_angaben_erschliessung = $immo->xpath('./oi:zustand_angaben/oi:erschliessung/@erschl_attr');
    $zustand_angaben_altlasten = $immo->xpath('./oi:zustand_angaben/oi:altlasten');
    $zustand_angaben_baujahr = $immo->xpath('./oi:zustand_angaben/oi:baujahr');

    echo "Immobilie $i<br />";
    if(isset($zustand_angaben_zustand[0])) {
        echo $zustand_angaben_zustand[0] . "</br>";
    }

    if(isset($zustand_angaben_alter[0])) {
        echo $zustand_angaben_alter[0] . "</br>";
    }

    if(isset($zustand_angaben_erschliessung[0])) {
        echo $zustand_angaben_erschliessung[0] . "</br>";
    }

    if(isset($zustand_angaben_altlasten[0])) {
        echo $zustand_angaben_altlasten[0] . "</br>";
    }

    if(isset($zustand_angaben_baujahr[0])) {
        echo $zustand_angaben_baujahr[0] . "</br>";
    }   
    echo "<br /><br />";
    $i++;
}
```

**<kbd>[`eval.in demo`](https://eval.in/408744)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

As you run the xpath queries in parallel, they have all their order next to each other.

For your example in specific you yet don't really need xpath, the document looks like the perfect job for **SimpleXMLElement**, you can retrieve the data directly from it.

If you foreach over the objects you're interested in (here most likely *each* *immobilie* element) and then extract the data (filter away unset elements), it can work similar to the following example:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

foreach ($xml->immobilie as $immobilie) {
    $angaben = $immobilie->zustand_angaben;

    $data = [
        'letzte_modernisierung' => $angaben->letztemodernisierung,
        'zustand_art'           => $angaben->zustand['zustand_art'],
        'alter'                 => $angaben->alter['alter_attr'],
        'erschliessung'         => $angaben->erschliessung['erschl_attr'],
        'altlasten'             => $angaben->altlasten,
        'baujahr'               => $angaben->baujahr,
    ];

    echo " * Immobilie:\n";
    foreach(array_filter($data) as $label => $wert) {
        echo "   - $label: $wert\n";
    }
}
```

The output is (also: [online-demo](https://eval.in/413850)):

```
 * Immobilie:
   - altlasten: keine
 * Immobilie:
   - altlasten: keine
 * Immobilie:
   - altlasten: keine
 * Immobilie:
   - altlasten: nein
   - baujahr: ca. 1900
 * Immobilie:
   - zustand_art: ERSTBEZUG
   - alter: ALTBAU
   - altlasten: keine
   - baujahr: ca. 1989
```

Xpath is not bad at all, for a scenario like you have it here, I would then recommend you to use **DOMDocument** instead of **SimpleXMLElement** as it's more flexible with Xpath thanks to the *evaluate* method **DOMXpath** has.

In any case, you can further read on with this question that shows one **DOMDocument** and one **SimpleXMLElement** based solution for Xpath based data-retrieval from XML documents:

- [PHP XPath. Convert complex XML to array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31402767/367456)